# How to keep the X and Y bounds fixed when I plot geographical coordinates using mapview?

Tags: r, coordinates, mapping, plot, mapview

I am trying to plot occurrences in different months using the mapview () function

```
x=data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))   ## choose the original CSV file downloaded from ebird
jan=x[which(x$Month == "1"),] ## separate out data by each month, to be plotted later as desired
feb=x[which(x$Month == "2"),]
mar=x[which(x$Month == "3"),]
apr=x[which(x$Month == "4"),]
may=x[which(x$Month == "5"),]
jun=x[which(x$Month == "6"),]
jul=x[which(x$Month == "7"),]
aug=x[which(x$Month == "8"),]
sep=x[which(x$Month == "9"),]
oct=x[which(x$Month == "10"),]
nov=x[which(x$Month == "11"),]
dec=x[which(x$Month == "12"),]

mapview(jan, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, col.regions="green") # plot the data for january
```

I would similarly want to plot the data for all 12 months, but I can't figure how to keep the x-y bounds for each of those 12 months similar. It assumes a default bound, which varies each month depending on the max extent of the data in each month, which doesn't give me maps  that I can compare.

Is there a option to add a header label for the map as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by converting your points to `sf` objects and then `mapview` lets you use `hide=TRUE` when you add map layers. Then you can use all your points as a hidden map layer, and that sets the extent, and add the layer you want to see.

Here's a reproducible example. First make a data frame of points in (0,1) and (1,2) unit squares:

```
p1 = data.frame(x=runif(10,0,1),y=runif(10,0,1),ID=1)
p2 = data.frame(x=runif(10,1,2),y=runif(10,1,2),ID=2)
p = rbind(p1, p2)
```

Now convert to a spatial data frame (ideally you'd also set the coordinate system here but everything defaults to lat-long so nm):

```
library(sf)
ps = st_as_sf(p, coords=c("x","y"))
```

Now make a map of ID=1:

```
mapview(ps[ps$ID==1,]) + mapview(ps, hide=TRUE)
```

And one of ID=2:

```
mapview(ps[ps$ID==2,]) + mapview(ps, hide=TRUE)
```

and those maps should have the same extent. This should be applicable to your data.

Alternatively you might want to switch to a different mapping package, like `tmap`, which may have a bit more flexibility for web mapping. I've only considered `mapview` for quick views of spatial data, and not for constructing maps that might have use as complex visualisation needing lots of fine control.

Comment: thank you, this is very neat